# How to call a parameter list from a function in Julia

Tags: julia

how can I call function `dxdt` ? I don't know how to define `p` as a argument for calling the function.

```
type Params
    a::TypeOfA
    b::TypeOfB
    c::TypeOfC
end

_unpack(p::Params) = (p.a, p.b, p.c)

function dxdt(x, p::Params)
    a, b, c = _unpack(p)
    a*x^2 + b*x + c
end
```

Comment: It isn't obvious to me what you're asking here. The code you've provided runs just fine (assuming `a`, `b`, and `c` are subtypes of `Number`). That is eg `dxdt(10, Params(1,2,3))` works if `a`, `b`, and `c` are `Int`.

Comment: for example params has a lot of variable, when I want to call the function I don't want to write all variables, what should I do?

Comment: `dxdt(x, p::Params) = p.a*x^2 + p.b*x + p.c` <-- is there any problem with doing this?

Comment: Do you want to give p a default value?

Comment: I want to call a function and I didn't know how to use p as an argument. I thought I have to write all variables in it instead of p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your question just how you define a variable `p` of type `Params`?
For a = 1.0, b = 2.0, c = 3.0:

```
p = Params(1.0,2.0,3.0)
```

Which can be used in the following way:

```
type Params
       a::Float64
       b::Float64
       c::Float64
end

p = Params(1.0,2.0,3.0)

_unpack(p::Params) = (p.a, p.b, p.c)

function dxdt(x, p::Params)
       a, b, c = _unpack(p)
       a*x^2 + b*x + c
end

dxdt(1.0,p)
6.0
```

I think that's what you're asking but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Parameters.jl](https://github.com/mauro3/Parameters.jl). It has a macro for doing this with more sugar and less typing. I think that's what you're looking for?

```
using Parameters

@with_kw type A
  a::Int = 6
  b::Float64 = -1.1
  c::UInt8
end

# Safe Way
function dxdt(x, p)
    @unpack a,b,c = p # This works on any type
    a*x^2 + b*x + c
end

# Easy Way
function dxdt(x, p)
    @unpack_A p # This only works on instances of A
    a*x^2 + b*x + c
end
```

Comment: Why are you telling `safe way`? How and why u call a function by `@` at the first of that?

Comment: It's generally thought to be safer to be explicit when programming. `@unpack_A p` doesn't tell you (inside of that function) exactly what values are unpacked because it's automatic. This makes it more prone to overwrite something on accident.